# AppCompact v21 back navigation with fragment menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-appcompat, android-menu, android-toolbar

So.. I'm facing a problem that has been driving me crazy for the past hours.

I have an App using the AppCompact v21 and toolbar. I also handle back navigation using:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

In combination with the parent activity on the manifest. Which works perfect....

My problem is:

I have an activity with 3 tabs with a viewpager and I need one of the fragments to have it's own menu.

I can inflate the menu just fine but once the menu is inflated the back arrow in that fragment don't work anymore. In the other 2 fragments of the view pager the back navigation through the toolbar still works.

Inside my fragment:

```
// Inside onCreate...
this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);

// Later on somewhere else...
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_submit, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    // my menu logic goes here.
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you always return `true` in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, that means you've handled every menu item possible (including the Up button). You should instead return `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)` in cases where you do not handle one of your items:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Your menu logic such as
    case R.id.your_menu_item:
      // Do something
      return true;
    default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```